How do you get the order total to update after modifying checkout line items?
I am trying to modify order line sub/totals after order submit using the hook 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item'. I can change the values, and they show up correctly in the order email, but the order total doesn't update.
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'css_modify_order', 10, 4);
function css_modify_order($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    $item->set_subtotal(50);
    $item->set_total(50);
}

I thought, since this is modifying the order item before it is added to the order, that WooCommerce would get the correct total amount further along in its code execution, before the order is saved.
I have tried using $item->save(); and $item->apply_changes(), but there was no change in the order total. $order->save_items() throws an error, and $order->save() has no effect.
I must be missing something. How do you modify an order item and have the order total come out correctly?

Thank you, Loic! That works, but I don't understand why we have to tell WooCommerce to calculate the total. Seems like it should do that by itself after the order items have been added.

I have answered your question below explaining things…

Ah, I see!  The function set_data_from_cart() calls $order->set_total() before create_order_line_items(). Thank you for helping me better understand the code flow!

As WooCommerce Totals are pre-calculated when submitting an order based on the cart items, if you make changes to those items like you are actually doing, you need to tell WooCommerce to recalculate totals.
For that purpose, you should use WC_Abstract_Order calculate_totals() method once the order is created, with woocommerce_checkout_order_created hook:
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', function($order){ 
    $order->calculate_totals(); 
});

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
